# How to categorise datetime in to a new column based on the date range in python

Tags: python, datetime, datetime-format, python-datetime

]I have a column called as `datetime` of type `datetime64[ns]` and for eg: it is represented as `2019-10-27 06:00:00` I would like to create a new column called `waves` which groups the date interval from `datetime` column to different categorical values. For eg:

> `Before covid: 16th of Nov 2019 until 28th of Feb 2020   First wave: 1st of Mar 2020 until 15th of Jun 2020   Between waves: 16th of Jun 2020 until 30th of Sep 2020   Second wave: 1st of Okt 2020 until 15th of Jan 2021`

How do I achieve this in python maybe using a loop function?

My dataset called `df` looks like this:

```
provider            fid        pid             datetime     
0   CHE-223      2bfc9a62   2f43d557       2021-09-26T23:18:00  
1   CHE-223      fff669e9   295b82e2       2021-08-13T09:10:00 
2   CHE-223      8693e564   9df9c555       2021-11-05T20:03:00
```

Comment: Can you send what dataset you're using please?

Comment: Hi there. I have edited now the question with my datatset. I would really appreciate a solution.

Comment: Is the data set shown good enough to understand?